# issue with expandable list android child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable `list` in Android and when click into child i visible and invisible some `View`. My issue is that i have to click multi click to do the action. How i can make this action on just one click.

**Below is my code:**

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,long id) {
            final View container =v.findViewById(R.id.container);
            TextView tvQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
            tvQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (container.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: try removing the click listener on tvQuestion so that the  onChildClick event will trigger your visibility operations

Comment: when i remove tvQuestion                         container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
not working its just being VISIBLE and cannot gone !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add clickListner In Adapter like this.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...your code...


tvQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (container.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for replay but when i do this ,, this give wrong child position

Comment: i put it inside getchildView but give me wrong position for example when i click to child number 1  ,, child number 5 effect not one !!

Comment: im not sure but is it right to set the visibility to GONE? Just replace it with INVISIBLE